# Derivative of matrix in quadratic optimization problem

Tags: matrices, derivatives, optimization, quadratics, matrix-calculus

$$
g(x) =\min_y f(x, y) =\min_y x^TAx + 2x^TBy + y^TCy
$$
where $x\in \mathbb R^{n\times 1}$, $y\in \mathbb R^{m\times 1}$, $A\in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$, $B\in \mathbb R^{n\times m}$, $C\in \mathbb R^{m\times m}$.
How to compute the derivative: $\frac{d g}{d x}$?

Comment: Try http://www.matrixcalculus.org

Comment: The problem is that $y$ depends on $x$ so you can not directly use the existing formula to compute the derivative. Note that $y=y(x)=argmin_y f(x, y)$.

Comment: Assuming that your problem is convex, you derive the quadratic part by $y$ and set to zero to find $g(x)$. That gives: $y=-2(C+C^T)^{-1}B^Tx$. Then you have $g(x)$ that depends only on $x$ so computing the derivative explicitly is easy. It's a 5 minutes work using the matrix calculus tool above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$
\def\a{\lambda}
\def\B{BC^{-1}B^T}
\def\o{{\tt1}}\def\p{\partial}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
$Although not explicitly stated I'll assume that $A\:{\rm and}\:C$ are symmetric matrices.

Perform the inner minimize by calculating the gradient wrt $y$ and setting it to zero
$$\eqalign{
\a &= y^TCy + 2(B^Tx)^Ty + x^TAx \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad \\
d\a &= (2Cy + 2B^Tx)^Tdy + 0 \\
\grad{\a}{y} &= 2\LR{Cy + B^Tx} \:=\: 0 \\
w &= y_{opt} \,=\, -C^{-1}B^Tx \\
}$$
This produces an explicit expression for $g(x)$
$$\eqalign{
g(x) &= f(x,w) \\
 &= x^TAx + 2x^TBw + w^TCw \\
 &= x^TAx - 2x^TBC^{-1}B^Tx + \LR{C^{-1}B^Tx}^TC\LR{C^{-1}B^Tx} \\
 &= x^T\LR{A-2\B+\B}x \\
 &= x^T\LR{A-\B}x \\
}$$
whose gradient is a trivial calculation
$$\eqalign{
\grad{g}{x} &= 2\LR{A-BC^{-1}B^T}x \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad \\
}$$

Answer (score 0):

The [envelope theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envelope_theorem) should be helpful.

Comment: This should be a comment unless you're willing to explain more as to how it would help i think

Comment: I do not have enough reputation to comment. Could you please comment on it for me? Then I will delete this reply.